# Sharepoint online List title with multiple lines

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

is there an easy way to change a List title formatting or appearance?

I would like to have the List title in multiple lines.

In alternative I would like to use a smaller font, maybe it could be possibile using the JSON formatting of the List view?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but if you want to control the format of that column in every view it appears, you need to use [JSON **column** formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting), **not** view formatting.

Although combing values from multiple columns is the more common scenario, [example #5 from this blog post](http://blog.vitalyzhukov.ru/en/sharepoint-online-column-json-formatting) shows how to split values apart with column formatting.

Note that you have to be using modern views for this to be an option.  If you are still using classic views, some old-fashioned jquery DOM manipulation may be your easiest option.